# Swift: Initialization of UIViewController subclass with custom parameters

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

The Problem:
I have a view controller, that holds two variables, without which the controller isn't able to work. So, by concept, those variables are mandatory or non-optional.

However, I declared them optional, which results in guard statement in the first lines of nearly every single method.
The reason for making them optional is:

- I'm not able to give them reasonable default values, they need to be set from outside during initialization
- I initialize the controller with `storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so there is no way (as far as I know) to define my own initializer which takes the necessary values. This would, obviously my favorite solution.
- I don't want to make them non-optional just by declaration (!), to avoid runtime problems, that could be solved by them compiler

Variable declaration:

```
    var dataSource : MyDataSource?
    var cellAndHeaderManager: MyCellAndHeaderManager?
```

Typical method start:

```
    guard let cellAndHeaderManager = cellAndHeaderManager else {return UICollectionReusableView()}
    let header = cellAndHeaderManager.headerForSection(collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
    guard let dataSource = dataSource else {return header}
```

Initialization:

```
     if let newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as? MyCollectionViewController {
            newController.dataSource = dataSource
            newController = cellAndHeaderManager
        }
```

What I'd like to do:

```
newController = MyCollectionViewController(dataSource, cellAndHeaderManager)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to initialize them as in  var dataSource : MyDataSource = MyDataSource() to avoid optionals

Comment: Because it's a generic view controller which gets its specific behavior via different implementations of data sources and cell managers, i.e. every instance of a view controller gets its own data source/cell manger, which are instances of different classes.

Comment: You can not instantiate view controller from Storyboard with initializer because there is no suitable initializer in UIViewController. So the only option is `class func` as in my answer.

Comment: Someone down-voted this question as well as @mixel 's good answer without leaving a comment... This is very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `class func` for your view controller:

```
class MyViewController {
    // ...
    class func instantiate(dataSource: MyDataSource, cellAndHeaderManager: MyCellAndHeaderManager) -> MyViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! MyViewController
        vc.dataSource = dataSource
        vc.cellAndHeaderManager = cellAndHeaderManager
        return vc
    }
}
```

So you can instantiate it with:

```
let vc = MyViewController.instantiate(dataSource: dataSource, cellAndHeaderManager: cellAndHeaderManager)
```

You can not instantiate view controller from Storyboard with initializer because there is no suitable initializer in `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a suitable solution. Together with private override of public initializers, that should do the job.

Comment: What about initializers , xcode giving error that no initializers

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Implement them https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#topics. Just call `super.init(...)` in their body.

Comment: Thanks  @mixel will try